# add Value to my multiPart in Junit (using jersey)

Tags: java, rest, junit, jersey

Hello i met an issue when testing my jersey web service with junit. I tried to add a value in my param

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response parsingPdfOrange(@FormDataParam("fichier") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("fichier") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
        @FormDataParam("TypeFacture") String typeFile) {
    try {
        // my code //

        return Response.status(201).entity(info).build();
}catch Exception e{
        return Response.status(406).entity("pb").build();
}
```

but i have no idea to add my typeFile into my entity, i've tried this but the string isn't communicate and return a nullpointerexeption

```
    @Test
public void parsePDF_TemplateNotExist() throws Exception {



        FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("fichier", new File(currentpath+FactureValide));
        BodyPart filePart2 = new BodyPart(templateName, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);

        FormDataMultiPart formDataMultipart = new FormDataMultiPart();
        FormDataMultiPart multipart = (FormDataMultiPart) formDataMultipart.bodyPart(filePart).bodyPart(filePart2);

        Response response = (target("pdf").request().post(Entity.entity(multipart, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)));
        System.out.println(currentpath);
        response.close();
        formDataMultipart.close();
}
```

i wish to know how i can resolve my pb and communicate the 2 entities for the test

Edit: this is my jsp
    <%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

```
<html>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding" />

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Envoi de fichier</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/rest/pdf" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileUploadForm">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Envoi de fichier</legend>
            <SELECT name="TypeFacture" id=typefacture>
            <option>Facture Orange</option>
            <option>Facture EDF</option>
            </SELECT>
            <label for="fichier">Emplacement du fichier <span class="requis">*</span></label>
            <input type="file" id="fichier" name="fichier" accept=".pdf" />
            <br />

            <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" id="btn_envoyer"/>
            <br /> 

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just use `BodyPart`, you don't get the `Content-Disposition` header, which has the name of the body part. `BodyPart` is more a more generic multipart. What you want is specifically multipart *form-data*. For that you can use `FormDataBodyPart`. It has the following constructor

```
FormDataBodyPart(String name, Object entity, MediaType mediaType)
```

Here you can specify the name or the body part, and this name is what's use to extract it with your `@FormDataParam` annotation. So you can use

```
FormDataBodyPart filePart2
    = new FormDataBodyPart("TypeFacture", templateName, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);
```

Instead of creating a `FormDataBodyPart`, you can also just use the `field` method of the `FormDataMultiPart`. So you could also just do

```
FormDataMultiPart formDataMultipart = new FormDataMultiPart()
    .field("TypeFacture", templateName, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);
```

Or even easier, if it is just a plan text part, you can leave of the `MediaType` and it will automatically set it to `text/plain`

```
FormDataMultiPart multipart = (FormDataMultiPart) new FormDataMultiPart()
        .field("TypeFacture", templateName)
        .bodyPart(new FileDataBodyPart("fichier", new File("test.txt")));
```